# If a polynomial is zero on $\left[-\frac12,\frac12\right]$ then it is zero polynomial on $[-1,1]$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, analysis

If a polynomial is zero on $\left[-\frac12,\frac12\right]$ then it is zero polynomial on $[-1,1]$

this is a mistake i did on my exam. I mean I could not see that the statement holds, so my conclusion was wrong.

Could you please explain it.

Comment: Does "a polynomial is zero on [a,b]" mean that the polynomial is the zero polynomial or that a polynomial has a zero in [a,b]? In both case the answer ist true. If it is the zero polynomial it remains the zero polynomial, and a zero in $[-1/2, 1/2]$ is also a zero in $[-1,1]$.

Comment: Let $n$ be the degree of the polynomial. Can you find more than $n$ zeros in the interval?

Comment: I mean zero polynomial on $[-1/2,1/2]$ then also on $[1,1]$.

Comment: @Macavity Could you please elobarate?

Comment: The only polynomial that has infinitely many zero is the zero polynomial by the D'Alembert's theorem.

Comment: Suppose the polynomial is not the zero polynomial. Whatever be $n$, you can find more than that many distinct zeros. Hence there are more factors of form $(x-\alpha_i)$ than the degree, which gives a contradiction.